# Assert that a float is approximate to one of several values

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to use Fluent Assertions to verify that a vector projected onto its own axis is approximate to either `v.Length()` or `-v.Length()`.

I can assert that the projection is approximate: `result.Should().BeApproximately(v.Length())`

or I can assert that the projection is one of several results: `result.Should().BeOneOf(v.Length(), -v.Length())`

How can I combine the two?

Comment: This fluent style does get programmers in trouble all the time.  Can't you just write one after the other?  A semicolon can do wonders.

Comment: Unfortunately (as per the comments on Dennis' answer) that would result in an `and` operation; I'm looking for an `or`

Answer (score 0):

Why not do `result.Should().BeApproximately(v.Length()).And.BeApproximately(-v.Length())`?

Comment: That would have to be an OR, no?

Comment: Ah, and that concept unfortunately doesn't exist in FA